# How to aggregate events tag values into a single datadog's counter metric

Tags: python, datadog

I am [datadogpy](https://github.com/DataDog/datadogpy) for sending events in the following format to datadog:

`api.Event.create(title=title, text=text, tags=tags)`

Where `tags` is `[{"value": len(group_of_items)}, {"org": org}]`

I want to build a metric which will get the value of `value` tag (i.e: `len(group_of_items)`) and sum it with the current metric sum in datadog.

Currently, I have a metric which displays the number of events sent, but I don't know how to get the `value` tag and sum it..

[image]

Does someone know how to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: `statsd.count` is not supported in Python.

Further investigating `datadogpy`, there is a specific API for that purpose called [datadog.threadstats](https://datadogpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#datadog-threadstats) or via agent

> datadog.threadstats is a tool for collecting application metrics without hindering performance. It collects metrics in the application thread with very little overhead and allows flushing metrics in process, in a thread, or in a greenlet, depending on your application’s needs. Submission is done through the HTTP API.

Make sure you've [initialized](https://datadogpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization) `datadog` first.

And, you can use it as follow:

```
statsd.increment(name, value, tags=tags)
```

Where `value` is 1 by default, and can be any numeric value you want to increment your counter to.

Comment: It seems like this does not work when using the agent: `Submission is done through the HTTP API.`Is there any alternative in this case? 
Having `increment` providing a value would be the ideal situation, but it looks like it is not supported on Datadog.